# How to knit a nested choice in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm new to RMarkdown, and I've tried and searched everywhere, but have been unlucky so far.

The problem I'm trying to solve is the following:

I'm trying to knit some parameters in Rmarkdown, and have a GUI so I can select variables and obtain a table. However, I need this variables to be "nested" or hierarchical, or be a child or be conditioned of previous choices.

To be specific, in the code below using mtcars... How can I select only cars with 4 cylinders so the next choice becomes only the cars with 4 cylinders, instead of all the list of cars?

```
    title: "cars"
date: "x"
output: html_document
params:
  Cylinders:
    label: "Cylinders"
    value: NULL
    input: select
    choice: [ 8, 6, 4 ]
  Cars:
    label: "Cars"
    value: NULL
    input: select
    choice: [ Datsun 710, Merc 240D, Merc 230, Mazda RX4, Mazda RX4, Wag, Duster 360, Merc 450SE]
```

In this website [manipulateWidget](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/manipulateWidget/vignettes/manipulateWidgets.html) (please see: Updating an input control) there's an exact example of what I need, but with a table as output.

I hope you can help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You've now delved into Shiny territory and the spinning gray wait-circle of doom that comes with it. In other words, you're asking _alot_ from an R Markdown document and you're going to need to build a small Shiny app to do this if you really needs the cascading interactivity.

Comment: Hello @hrbrmstr !
First of all, thank you! :) I hope I can bring knowledge to SO.
Do you know any way to start building this small Shiny app?
Thanks.

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/